# localhost working perfectly fine but other created vhosts not working -showing 404 page error

Tags: server, localhost, apache2, http-status-code-404, vhosts

[image]My localhost is working perfectly fine but my virtualhost is not working. My created vhosts is giving me a "404 page not found" error
Here's a screenshoot of my testing.conf file[image: Here's the screenshot of my test.conf file]
When I checked the apache2 error log after a page refresh gives me a "404 page error" I get a file with no content, meaning no error. But,
when I restart the apache I get this in the apache2 error log.

[Thu Jul 08 18:08:47.037483 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 242161] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 08 18:08:47.037571 2021] [core:notice] [pid 242161] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of items that should be noted here:

1. "When I checked the apache2 error log after a page refresh gives me a 404 page error I get a file with no content, meaning no error"
   ⇢ This is not necessarily accurate. Your `testing.conf` file is writing the error log to `/var/www/testing/error.log`, which is not where Apache is expecting to write logs. You may need to grant Apache more permissions via AppArmor or write the logs in the proper `/var/log/apache` directory.
2. "when I restart the apache I get this in the apache2 error log"
   ⇢ That is normal. It's Apache's way of saying "The server was restarted".

Some items to look out for:

1. Your virtual host configuration file has specified port 8081. Is Apache configured to listen for traffic on this port?
2. There is no `<Directory>` record in your configuration file. Is `/var/www/testing` accessible to the host?

If you would like to have your virtual host respond to traffic over the default port 80, consider having your configuration file as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin enels@socials.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/testing/public_html

        ServerName testing
        ServerAlias testing *.testing testing.*
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/testing-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/testing-access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/testing/public_html>
               Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride All

               Order Allow,Deny
               Allow From All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You may not want the `ServerAlias` line but, if you decide to have subdomains or pseudo-TLDs (such as api.testing or testing.local), this will catch requests and direct them accordingly.